# Order By on cyrillic letters

Tags: sql, sql-server, unicode, sql-server-2012, sql-order-by

I want to provide a correct ordered list of names.

My question: is the SQL `ORDER BY` clause the best way to provide correct ordered strings in multiple languages or are there some problems which should be considered?

I just tested it with Russian letters and it seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sorting of a column depends on the `collation` in use for that column, or the optional collation applied to that sort - ie: `ORDER BY {column name} COLLATE {collation name}`

You would be advised to pick a collation that meets your requirements, perhaps `Cyrillic_General_CI_AS`

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143508(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Is the `collation` required in order to provide correct results? @podiluska

Comment: @Nico The collation defines the sort order. It depends what your interpretation of "correct results" is

Comment: A correct result for me is a correct ordered search result in every language. I tried it with english and cyrillic data and it worked both without collation. @podiluska

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM your_table
 ORDER BY nlssort(your_column, 'NLS_SORT=russian');

Answer (score -1):

SQL `order by` clause is the best way to show correct ordered list of names.

Comment: Please do provide some information, Like how its best way to order list of names by `ORDER BY` clause. That will help OP.